# How to receive html anchor tag value in Django views.py?

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to send string value from anchor tag in a div in html i.e "news.id"
to views.py. I'm not sure if "single_post/{{ news.id }}" is correct or not. news.id could be 5c9f94516fe3c761e420333a (for regex)

.html

```
<div class="post-continue-btn">
    <a href="single_post/{{ news.id }}"  class="font-pt">Continue Reading 
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

I've passed this one somehow but now stuck at URLs.py, here is my URL code

URL.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^single_post/$', views.single_post),
    url(r'^<slug:slug>/$',views.single_post),
    url(r'^index/single_post/$', views.single_post),
    url(r'^index/$', views.index),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact),
    url(r'^about_us/$', views.about_us),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

views.py

```
def single_post(request):
    project_name = request.GET.get('id')
    context = {'doc_data': search_query.doc_data(project_name)}
    return render_to_response('DeepNews/dummy.html', context)
```

How to code things right in .html anchor tag and then what will be the regex for this type of string "5c9f94516fe3c761e420333a" in URL.py so that I can get the value of "news.id" in views.py

Comment: Add a parameter to single post view and url

Comment: @geckos can you please code it according to your answer for me, I don't understand

Comment: It goes after the request parameter, just remove the second single post url and add the slug patter tk the end of the first single post url path

Comment: It goes after the request parameter, just remove the second single post url and add the slug patter tk the end of the first single post url path

Comment: In a minute, I'm on smartphone

Comment: @geckos Please check the html and views.py too. in case they have some mistake too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

On your urls pass the parameter to the single post url, also give it a name so you avoid hard coded urls on your app

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^single_post/(?P<uuid>[a-z0-9-]*)/', views.single_post, name='sigle-post'),
    url(r'^index/$', views.index),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact),
    url(r'^about_us/$', views.about_us),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

On template you can then tell to django construct the url for you by using the `url` tag

```
<div class="post-continue-btn">
    <a href="{% url 'single-post' news.id %}"  class="font-pt">Continue Reading 
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

And on your view you receive the argument

```
def single_post(request, uuid):
    project_name = uuid
    context = {'doc_data': search_query.doc_data(project_name)}
    return render_to_response('DeepNews/dummy.html', context)
```

Comment: TypeError at /single_post/5c9f8655febdaf1e306afd3b/
single_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uuid'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/single_post/5c9f8655febdaf1e306afd3b/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
single_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uuid'
Exception Location: C:\Users\mursa\Anaconda2\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 124
Python Executable: C:\Users\mursa\Anaconda2\envs\myDjangoEnv\python.exe @geckos can you please help me solve this?

Comment: So it almost work. Your view was called as `single_post(request, uuid='something')` does it have the uuid parmeter? You renamed it? If so you need to rename the uuid part of the url at urls.py too

Comment: `url(r'^single_post/(?P<HERE>[a-z0-9-]*)/'`

Comment: Django will use the grouped name as a keyword argument of your view, so if you have a url `r'(?P<foo>.*?)/', my_view)`, you need `my_view` to accept `foo` keyword, `def my_view(request, foo)`. You can make the parameter optional by giving a default value in the view too `def my_view(request,foo=None)`

Comment: I copied your entire code and pasted it there, didn't make any changes other than the correction from 'sigle-post' to 'single_post' and replaced '-' with underscore in href single_post

Comment: The first `url` argument in templates correspond to the `name=` argument of urlsm try to replace the dash at urls.py too at `name='single-post'`

Comment: Thank you so much for your guide, I'll let you know when I make a progress

Comment: If the answer helped you, please, can you mark it as the right one? I'm glad to help!

Comment: I made some changes to the code you sent me, I'll quote them all, please update your answer so it works directly for someone who is in search:

Comment: URL.py:     name='sigle-post' to     name='single_post'
.html:     <a href="{% url 'single-post' news.id %}" to     <a href="{% url 'single_post' uuid=news.id %}"

Comment: urls.py `name='single_post`, .html `{% url 'single_post' news.id %}`

Comment: in html news.id to uuid=news.id

Comment: but I was getting this error without defining it as uuid = news.id "single_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uuid'"

Comment: Just keep the `uuid =  news.id` so, is a better practice :)

Comment: @geckos I want to tell you that if I print the same uuid in html, it prints the id like "c9f94516fe3c761e420333a" as required, but when I get it in views.py and print it on command line, it prints id along with "jpg", "jpg", "png" as extra data which I do not require. What am I suppose to do? How to get rid of this junk data? I tried print(uuid[0]) but then it prints the first letter of all the strings like "c", "j", "j", "p". Please help me

Comment: `uuid.split('.')[0]` would do it. Search for split function

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'(?P<single_post>[^/]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', views.single_post, name='sigle-post'),
    url(r'^index/single_post/$', views.single_post),
    url(r'^index/$', views.index),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact),
    url(r'^about_us/$', views.about_us),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

Comment: TypeError at /single_post/5c9f94516fe3c761e420333a/

Comment: single_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

Comment: @SheikhAmaanAsghar check  my updated answer, also make sure to [check this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/references/2016/10/10/url-patterns.html)

Comment: @lakovos TypeError at /single_post/5c9f94516fe3c761e420333a/ 
single_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'single_post'

Comment: Can I see your view?

Comment: @lakovos Thank you so much for your help, the other answer solved the issue with some minor changes I made. I'm not an expert and needed all the code to be oriented according to the situation I was facing. Thanks to (@)geckos, he wrote the entire html, view.py and url.py code for me >_<

Comment: @SheikhAmaanAsghar I am glad you found your solution

Comment: @lakovos I want to tell you that if I print the same uuid in html, it prints the id like "c9f94516fe3c761e420333a" as required, but when I get it in views.py and print it on command line, it prints id along with "jpg", "jpg", "png" as extra data which I do not require. What am I suppose to do? How to get rid of this junk data? I tried print(uuid[0]) but then it prints the first letter of all the strings like "c", "j", "j", "p". Please help me

Comment: First with the help of type() see what data structure returned and maybe try to .split()